# MPMoviePlayerController rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

How to rotate the video player in iOS programming using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

My code:

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
 moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: As you are adding the player onto some viewController's view, the rotation should be handled by the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the bounds and rotating the view like this:

```
[[moviePlayer view] setBounds:CGRectMake(20, 0, 480, 350)];
[[moviePlayer view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
playerControlsContainer.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Hi Grangji,You wrote code for horizontal transform, i am asking how to rotate video player dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
      {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(ChangedmyMPMoviePlayerController :)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
      }


     -(void) ChangedmyMPMoviePlayerController:(NSNotification *)notification
      {
        [self adjustMPMoviePlayerController:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
      }


- (void) adjustMPMoviePlayerControlle:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{ 
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];    
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; 
}}
```

Comment: Hi, This is not working properly, can you please write code for, how to rotate video content using MPMoviePlayerController?